# OrdinalEncoder not handling unknown values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to use an OrdinalEncoder to classify categorical features (for which ordinal makes sense, like income categories etc.). However, in the dataset I am using, all the missing values are set as 'Unkown' instead of NaN.
Hence, I am trying to define the categories to be classified manually, and handle 'unknowns' with the *handle_unknown* and *unknown_value = np.nan* arguments.
I also tried to set *handle_unknown = ignore*, but it did not work as it does with OneHotEncoder. Below the code (adapted to be reproducible with the smaller df linked below)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    


cst_cat = pd.read_csv('YOUR PATH HERE')
cat_s = cat_s = [['Existing Customer','Attrited Customer'],['M', 'F'],['Uneducated', 'High School','College',  'Graduate',  'Post-Graduate','Doctorate'],['Less than $40K','$40K - $60K', '$60K - $80K', '$80K - $120K','$120K +'],['Blue', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Platinum']]
cols_cat = cst_cat.columns


ord_enc = OrdinalEncoder(categories = cat_s, handle_unknown = 'use_encoded_value', unknown_value = np.nan)


cst_cat = ord_enc.fit_transform(cst_cat)
cst_cat = pd.DataFrame(cst_cat, columns = cols_cat)
cst_cat.head()
```

When I run my code, however, I get

```
ValueError: Found unknown categories ['Unknown'] in column 2 during fit
```

where column 2 is simply the first one in which I encounter that value.

I already found a temporary fix assigning unknowns to specific values I then replace with the median, but does anyone know how to get the encoder to work?

Here's the dataset (in a smaller version)
https://github.com/TheCodingCvrlo/ml/blob/churn_predictor/small.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate the OrdinalEncoder method like this:

```
OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value', unknown_value=np.nan)
```

OrdinalEncoder has two parameters handle_unknown{‘error’, ‘use_encoded_value’} and unknown_value a you can see in the documentation in the parameters section https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html

Answer (score -1):

Try using `ord_enc = OrdinalEncoder(categories = cat_s, handle_unknown='ignore', unknown_value = np.nan)`

Comment: This answer is currently unclear. It would benefit future readers if an explanation was added and the code was put into context.